# How do I make my template require only absolutely necessary functions

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Sorry new poster here and really couldn't phrase my question particularly well.  Also apologize for any breaches in etiquette ahead of time. I am working on templatizing a class. I pass two tests on it but I fail the third test: This class provides a minimal set of operations and, as
      such, represents a test of whether your MiniMax class
      requires its data to support more functions than are absolutely
      necessary.

```
template <class Data>
void MiniMax<Data>::observe (const Data& t)
{
  if (count == 0)
    min = max = t;
  else
    {
      if (t < min)
    min = t;
      if (t > max)
    max = t;
    }
  ++count;
}
```

It fails at the line `if(t>max)` with no match for operator> during compilation.  How do I alter my template so it doesn't require > to be implemented in the user-defined class? In this assignment, I can only edit the template and not any of the test drivers.

Comment: You could instead do `if (max < t) {` which'll reuse the `operator<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Anthony Sottile said in the comments the simplest way to do this would be to switch the placement of the operands and change the operator, changing `t > max` to `max < t`. This reuses the operator and still does the same thing.

After changing it your code would look like this:

```
if (count == 0)
   min = max = t;
else
{
    if (t < min)
        min = t;
    if (max < t) // <-- Difference Here
        max = t;
}
++count;
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work, submitting now we'll see if the autograder likes it. This seems like an arbitrarily crumby thing to do in an assignment so I'm not sure it's exactly what the professor is looking for. Any other way to do it that you can think of?

Comment: Not with a single operator. You could do `!(t < max) && t != max` but that still uses two operators. If you don't mind setting `max` to `t` when they are equal you could only do `!(t < max)` but that changes what your program actually does.

Comment: That does work but then it fails the other tests which specifically look for the > operator.  Is there anyway to split the three tests  (=,<,>) somehow?

Comment: You could specialize the template function depending on whether `Data` has an `operator >` using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence).

Comment: Apparently swapping >with < was what he was looking for. Thanks again!